# on_voice_state_update() not running as expected when going [vc -> vc]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The following code is meant to change the name of a voice channel depending on what game is being played. It works perfectly when the state change is `[NONE -> vc]` & `[vc -> None]` but not when going `vc -> vc`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    
    channel = before.channel
    print("debug 1")
    try:
        print("debug 2")
        if len(channel.members) == 0:
            print("debug 3")
            if str(channel.name).startswith("Currently"):
                print("debug 4")
                await channel.edit(user_limit=0, name="|Dormant", overwrites=discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False))
                await asyncio.sleep(600)
                await channel.edit(name="Waiting for game to be played...", roles=None, reason="The voice channel was empty")
                await channel.set_permissions(role=discord.Role.name())
        else:
            print("debug 5")
    except Exception:
        print("Leaving phase was not called")
        
    try:
        channel = after.channel
        print(f"There was an update in id: {channel.id}")
        if channel.name == "Waiting for game to be played...":
            print(f"user {member.name} joined")
            new_name = f"Currently playing: {discord.utils.get(member.activities, type=discord.ActivityType.playing)}"
            member_names = channel.members
            await channel.edit(name=new_name, roles=None, reason=f"{member_names[0]} started playing {new_name}")
    except Exception:
        print("Joining phase was not called")
```

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

The expected behavior is that the name of the old channel will be switched to "|Dormant" if it's empty, and no changes will be made if it's not. The new channel should also have it's name switched to whatever game is being played in said channel, see: `await channel.edit(name=new_name, roles=None, reason=f"{member_names[0]} started playing {new_name}")`

**Edit:**

I made some changes to the code and now it runs the joining phase when going `[vc -> vc]` but not the leaving phase in any instance `([vc -> vc], [vc -> None])`

Comment: fix me if im wrong.. so you want to make something likes "log" for monitoring your member joining or leaving what channel?

Comment: I want the name of the channel to be representative of what the first user that joined the channel is playing, all `print()` calls are just for debugging. All "logging" is done through the `reason=reason` arg in `channel.edit()`

Comment: `what the first user that joined the channel is playing`, what does this mean? Just log who and when a person joined a channel? Maybe you should add at the beginning `if statement` to check before channel is None and after is not None

Comment: Don't catch `Exception` and print a generic error message - it will hide the _real_ error message generated underneath. When debugging, don't catch the exception at all, unless you want to actually handle the issue in a specific way - and then you catch the _specific_ exception and not the general `Exception` class. Any issue within either code path will now be hidden away and you'll have to guess at what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe for the beginning you should make. This checking when your action take field.

```
if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
   ## do your stuff here
   
elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
   ## do your stuff here
```

I use this one for logging and monitoring someone who and when he/she joined channel in my server.

Comment: What difference does it make to have `else stuff` compared to `elif stuff`?

Comment: @Oskar ```else stuff``` is the same as ```else``` as ```stuff``` is unreachable. If you want ```stuff``` to have an effect then you should use ```elif```